# Which is the suitable toroid ring to wind the gate drive transformer of a SSTC?

Tags: tesla-coil

I found this “ferrite” (i’m not sure if its ferrite) ring from a SMPS. A choke, to be specific. It’s made of black- grey, very hard, brittle material. Lower density than a solid iron ring. Is it OK to wind a GDT with it? If not, what would be suitable?
Edit: large resistance, in the tens of kilo ohms scale

Comment: It's almost definitely ferrite.

Comment: The core you should use depends on frequency among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Toroidal cores you find in old power supplies and whatnot which are used for chokes will NOT work for Tesla coil gate drive transformers. They tend to be made up of iron filings or iron powder and their permeability is VERY low. You really need to purchase known cores from a trusted distributor. The permeability must be very high, > 8000 and preferably > 10,000. For my GDTs and CTs which I use on my DRSSTC I used [TDK B64290L0674X038](https://www.tdk-electronics.tdk.com/inf/80/db/fer/r_36_0_23_0_15_0.pdf) and they work great.

[image]